# TinyMCE editor height won't change

Tags: html, angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am new to tinymce and using the editor with angularJS. I am using the tinymce library 4.3.13
Using the following HTML and angularJS code to generate the tinymce editor. When rendering the editor in UI the height becomes very small(75px) it won't set the assigned height in the tinymceOptions object. Tried many solutions but couldn't come up with a solution. Highly appreciate any help.

```
<textarea class="form-control" ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" rows="16" required></textarea>

$scope.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins: [
            'autoresize advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample'
        ],
        autoresize_bottom_margin : 5,
        menubar:false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar: 'undo redo cut copy paste pastetext alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist outdent indent bold italic underline strikethrough formats removeformat fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor link hr',
        height: 400,
        width: 1200,
        theme: 'modern',
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "autoresize",
  selector: '#editor',
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  autoresize_min_height: 100,
  autoresize_max_height: 1000,
  autoresize_bottom_margin: 0,
  allow_conditional_comments: true
});
```

please look at [autoresize plugin tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/autoresize/) documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the selector with textarea id but, nothing worked for me.

Comment: we cannot have duplicate properties "selector"

Comment: autoresize_min_height: 100, autoresize_max_height: 1000, properties done the job. Thank you so much for you're solution

Comment: i did not get you @Harshana

Comment: I used height: 400, autoresize_min_height: 400, autoresize_max_height: 1000, properties in my tinymceOptions object and now it doesn't set the default height 75px and take height from options object.